# How to auto generate NSManagedObject subclasses with date attribute as Date instead of NSDate?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, nsdate, nsmanagedobject

I'm currently updating my project to Swift 3 and I'm moving all my NSDate methods and extensions to Date in order to keep the standard in the app.

The problem is that I use Xcode to auto-generate my NSManagedObject subclasses and it is generating the date attributes as NSDate instead of Date.

Is there a way to generate it with the date attributes as Date?

### EDIT

Per [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content///documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH30-SW1):

> Core Data natively supports a variety of attribute types, such as string, date, and integer (represented as instances of NSString, NSDate and NSNumber respectively).

So I think it's not possible =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently possible, because Core Data is still very much tied to Objective-C types, and this is one of the places it shows.

However, you can still assign a `Date` to an `NSDate` attribute:

```
    newEvent.timestamp = Date() as NSDate
```

It's far from ideal, but if you have other code that uses `Date`, you don't have to make it use `NSDate` instead. Use `as` to convert only when working directly with your managed objects.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! For now I'm manually changing the NSDate properties to Date inside NSManagedObject subclasses and it works properly. I was just trying to find a way to automatically generate with Date instead.

Comment: Bruno: Changing NSDate to Date may work (I'm trying that too), but of course that's a model change.  Doing that after the core data model is live requires a migration or loading the data will fail.  During initial development is ok.